# Access Violation Error when calling Matlab compiled function from C#

Tags: c#, matlab

I have a problem with calling Matlab function from C#. When I am calling Matlab function, the **Access Violation Error (0x00000005)** occurs.

**Simple Matlab function** was created:

```
function fcnHelloStrIn(str)

fprintf(sprintf('Hello world ... %s\n\n', (str)));
```

A **dll library** incorporating this function was created by Matlab compiler (4.17)

```
bool MW_CALL_CONV mlxFcnHelloStrIn(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, mxArray *prhs[]);
```

I tried to implement **simple C# wrapper** as follows (only relevant lines of code are included)

```
...

// ----- DLL import -----

[DllImport("HelloDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]

public static extern bool mlxFcnHelloStrIn([In] int nlhs, ref IntPtr outParams, [In] int nrhs, [In] IntPtr inParams);

...

MCR and Dll initialization function // OK

...

// ----- Main part -----

IntPtr outputPtr = IntPtr.Zero;

IntPtr stringPtr = IntPtr.Zero;

string helloString = "Hello world!";

stringPtr = mxCreateString(helloString);

bool result = mlxFcnHelloStrIn(0, ref outputPtr, 1, stringPtr);

....
```

When I call the function *mlxFcnHelloStrIn* then the access violation error (0xc0000005) arise. Does anybody know how to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance

Martin

Comment: Download the [C# MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/12987) samples and see where you're going wrong.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I think this example is for the case when **Matlab Builder** is used. I use the **Matlab Compiler** (and MCR) instead.